# How to track exceptions and results of nested futures in scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, future

I have a scenario where i want to compute nested futures. Below is the scenario:

```
def firstFuture(factor: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
    println("Running future 1")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    5 * factor
  }

  def secondFuture(factor: Int) = Future {
    println("Running future 2")
    throw new Exception("fjdfj")
    Thread.sleep(4000); 3 * factor
  }

  def thirdFuture = Future {
    println("Running future 3")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    throw new Exception("mai fat raha hu")
  }

  def method = {
    (Future(5).map { factor =>
      firstFuture(factor).recover { case ex: Exception => throw new Exception("First future failed") }
      secondFuture(factor).recover { case ex: Exception => throw new Exception("Second future failed") }
      thirdFuture.recover { case ex: Exception => throw new Exception("Third future failed") }
    }).flatMap(identity).recover { case ex: Exception =>
      println("Inside recover")
      println(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
  Await.result(method, 20 seconds)
```

I want to handle the exceptions of all the nested future where the main future completes. Suppose if secondFuture fails, then the outcome should be secondFuture failed. But i am only getting that reflected for the Third future. How can i achieve that. What should be the implementation.

Note: The nested three futures are supposed to run in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are only getting the error of the third future is because the value of the whole block is the last expression of the block, so

```
Future(5).map { factor =>
  firstFuture(factor)   // this executes but the result is discarded
  secondFuture(factor)  // this executes but the result is discarded
  thirdFuture           // the last expression becomes the value of the whole block
}
```

Also consider what happens when we have nested futures and we throw inside an inner future

```
Future(41).map { v =>
  Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom"))  // the exception is simply swallowed
  v + 1                                      
}
```

The result is `Future(42)` despite the exception thrown inside the inner `Future`. This is important to understand as otherwise we might introduce **silent failures** in the system.

To achieve your requirement [try](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/s8mhq10ATjCJlPUXKMXCuw) combination of for-comprehension and [`Future.sequence`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#sequence[A,CC[X]%3C:IterableOnce[X],To](in:CC[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom[CC[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,To],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[To])

```
for {
  factor <- Future(5)
  results <- Future.sequence(List(firstFuture(factor), secondFuture(factor), thirdFuture))
} yield results
```

The three futures passed to `sequence` will execute concurrently and `sequence` will return a failed future if any one of them fails.